# Sqlite3, SELECT Query

Tags: sqlite, select, conditional-statements

my table looks something like this:

| index | ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x | *NULL* |
| 2 | 1 | y | *NULL* |
| 3 | 1 | z | 123 |
| 4 | 2 | x | 456 |
| 5 | 2 | y | *NULL* |
| 6 | 2 | z | 789 |
| 7 | 3 | x | 1011 |
| 8 | 3 | y | *NULL* |
| 9 | 3 | z | *NULL* |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |

so my aim is to select only values where the name is 'z' and not *NULL*. The second condition is that the values that correspond to the name 'x' and 'y' are *NULL*. In the table above this would only be the value with the Rowindex '3'. I'm new to sqlite3 and it would be a pleasure for me if someone could help me.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause which checks for the max value of `Name` for the corresponding `ID` when `Name` is `'x'` or `'y'`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.Name = 'z'
  AND (
    SELECT MAX(t2.Value) 
    FROM tablename t2 
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Name IN ('x', 'y')
  ) IS NULL
```

Or, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.Name = 'z'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tablename t2 
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Name IN ('x', 'y') AND t2.Value IS NOT NULL
  )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1043193bd90340664ef53ea93b2fabec).